# Powershell 7: Issue with Where-Object and tags

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, powershell-7

I am running a simple powershell query in Azure. I am looking to filter only the Web Apps with a certain Tag assigned to it:

```
$apps = Get-AzWebApp | Where-Object {$_.Tags["Application"] -match "any-tag-value"} 

if ($apps) {
    foreach ($app in $apps) {
        Write-Host $app.Name
    }
}
```

Regardless, if it finds anything or not, the first two results are always `InvalidOperation: Cannot index into a null array.`. After that it lists what it finds.

If I remove the Where-Object clause everything works fine.

I am not sure why this error occurs and what are these two empty arrays that go into the resultset.

Anyone can shed light into this?

Comment: if the resource you're querying doesn't have any tag set it would make sense that it throws that error. Change your filtering to: `Where-Object { $_.Tags -and $_.Tags["Application"] -match "any-tag-value"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the first 2 resources listed by your cmdlet don't have a tag set and referencing a property that is not set will be `null` and then indexing a `null` value causes the exception you're seeing:

```bash
([pscustomobject]@{ }).PropertyDoesNotExist['foo']

# Throws: InvalidOperation: Cannot index into a null array.
```

The easiest workaround for this can be via dot notation and let [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.4) handle the indexing for you, that way:

```bash
$apps = Get-AzWebApp | Where-Object { $_.Tags.Application -match "any-tag-value" }
```

Or, you can first check if such property exist and then try to index it:

```bash
$apps = Get-AzWebApp | Where-Object { $_.Tags -and $_.Tags['Application'] -match "any-tag-value" }
```